# Should I do anything about a plagiarism flag I raised 17 days ago that's still pending?

Tags: discussion, flags, plagiarism

On November 5th, I saw a poor answer to a question that, amongst other things, looked like it was answering a similar question with different details. So I did a quick search and found that the answer was a verbatim copy of a different user's answer to a similar question on a different SE site.

As this was blatant plagiarism (no attribution, no modification at all, verbatim) I flagged it with the text "Blatant plagarism:" followed by a link to the original post.

The flag remains "pending" 17 days later (and the answer is still there).

Do I do anything? Or just wait?

Comment: This is why there's a moderator election going on right now, there's a big backlog in working down the custom flag queue.  They'll get to it, eventually.

Comment: Plagiarism is almost never an isolated incident; it is probably worth checking out that user's other contributions.

Comment: Just wait. Plagairsm flags are important and when well written can be really helpful, but they're always  time sucker. It can take well over 30 minutes to do just 1 such flag justice and the flag queue has been massive for quite a while now.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think I see why this got buried in the "other" flags and wasn't handled as quickly as similar flags. This is the text of your flag:

> Blatant plagarism: [URL]

In order to better group "other" flags (which can be for every action under the sun) some of us are using a prototype flag filtering script. The filtering for the plagiarism grouping picks out all flags with "plagia" or "copied" in them. The minor typo in your above flag meant that it was not picked up by this filter, so it fell back into the unsorted pile of "other" flags. I regularly sweep through plagiarism flags and try to handle those quickly, but this one didn't come up.

We've been burning down this pile after the return of several moderators, and yours was one of the oldest "other" flags still remaining. It was surrounded by trickier problems or ones that may require SE employee intervention, so it got overlooked in there.

I took care of it, but I don't know that I'd call this a case of "blatant" plagiarism, as there wasn't any wording copied and the section of code used was drawn from within a block of code in the other answer you linked. That other answer looked like it might have been drawn from some example code, which this answer could have been, as well.

People reuse code all the time, so it's harder to judge whether cases like this are truly plagiarism. I've added a reference to the other answer to indicate possible sourcing, but I don't think this is bad enough to warrant deletion.

Comment: The "typo" has been repeated four times on this page including by another moderator. Perhaps the script could be adjusted to include this misspelling?

Comment: ^^ What Martin said. Thanks for handling the flag, Brad. I disagree about deleting the answer, it serves no purpose and is just copy-and-paste regurgitation, but then, I'm not standing as a moderator, either (this time, anyway). :-)

Comment: @MartinSmith - Like I said, it's a prototype that was quickly coded up by an SE employee. We tried to identify a few common keywords to sort things, but we haven't accounted for typos. Only a few moderators are using this, and it's completely experimental. It's a first stab at bringing some kind of categorization to this bag of flags.