# What should I do with an answer, which brings nothing new compared to already given ones?

Tags: discussion

I lately often see answers which repeats or just brings the same idea as the one(s) that have already been posted. I deem it as a simple chase of points, as if (arguably) better wording or something would attract the OP attention.

Recent example:

[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33883697/redirect-user-to-signup)

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34033980/1772830) given 4 hours ago (from now)

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34035305/1772830) given 1 hour ago (newest and repeating the old one)

In the provided example the latter answer somehow got an upvote, but it really is nothing new in comparison with the older. The code sample is **the same** (with changed class name).

Comment: Seems like the problem's taken care of itself.  They deleted it about 7 minutes after you posed this question.

Comment: please comment on your downvote - be constructive.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko That is actually discouraged in the help center.

Comment: @TinyGiant, Where is that discouraged? I looked and couldn't find it. I usually leave a comment if i downvote, and I always like to get comments from down-voters on my questions/answers. It's good to know what is wrong/why the down-vote happened.

Comment: I was wrong, it is not explicitly discouraged in the help center. However, [the practice has been proven to be problematic](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251299/4639281) and people should not be pestered or made to feel guilty if they don't leave a comment with their downvote. The default meaning of a downvote is either "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" or "This answer is not useful". If someone does not comment on their downvote then you can safely assume that the default reason applies. @Jakar

Comment: @TinyGiant, *and people should not be pestered or made to feel guilty if they don't leave a comment with their downvote.* - Yes. I totally agree.

Comment: Why would you want to do something?

Comment: @Bardware because it is purest pollution. I use SO. I do not want to see repeated answer few times. But what I do not want to see even more, is people trying to dirty-earn those points. My actual reaction on such behavior is to delete the account once and for all. Fortunately for them, I ain't admin here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as @Grimby said in the comments to @Hans Passant's answer, my question [has already been answered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268630/1772830) here, on meta.

From the answer (credits to [Cody Gray](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray)):

> You have a couple of choices:
>
> 1. Downvote the answer and leave a comment for the person who posted it,
>      explaining how serious plagiarism is and suggesting some corrective
>      steps. Do this only if you truly think that the person who posted the
>      answer did so in good faith.
> 2. Flag the answer for moderator attention, extensively documenting the
>      plagiarism that occurred by providing a link to the original source
>      and reminding the overworked moderators of the seriousness of this
>      issue. Request that the answer be deleted.

I am sorry for the duplicate question.

Now I totally know what to do.

Answer (score 15):

It should make you suspicious and give you a reason to look at the user's profile, reviewing his reputation changes.  Pretty obvious why he posted that answer from there.

This kind of voting fraud is very common.  How they dodge the vote checking script is a big mystery but appears to be widely spread knowledge.  Flag one of his posts with a custom flag, I recommend "Fake post, sock puppet voting on this user's account not getting detected", and those puppets will get larsoned.

Comment: Hm, I have no doubts you could be right regarding voting fraud and this things, - if I ever notice something like this I will follow your advice - thanks! But my question was more about the case, when a person consciously adds no value to discussion by adding an answer almost identical to existing onу.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko then you go to meta and you search "duplicate answer" and go through the results :) http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268629/how-do-we-deal-with-plagiarized-answers (that's specifically plagiarism, there are plenty of other results)

Comment: @Gimby you are 1000% right, thanks for link and sorry for actually asking a duplicate question - my bad (my first question on meta)

Comment: I am curious about the voting fraud, has all of the evidence been cleaned up already or am I just not seeing it?

Comment: It is still there.  Most visible for Nov 27, check the times.

Comment: "Larsoned" is a word? I'm not sure whether to be flattered or offended.

Comment: @Fred: You know that one of our diamond mods is named "[Brad Larson](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson)"?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes, although he didn't come to mind. Is that where the term came from? I was wondering if it was derived from this: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Larsoned

Comment: @Fred: I'm pretty sure that Hans is using it in the sense of "a meeting with moderator Brad Larson in a dark and disused corner of the network, which the account used for abusive voting will not much enjoy".

Answer (score 5):

The example is non-generic, so I being a non-expert in Ruby on Rails, can not comment if they are indeed the same answer.

But if it is, you have two option. Either downvote it or flag it as Custom flag to bring it in attention to a moderator. That's all you can do (As far I know). The answer may or may not have plagiarized the previous answer. They might have started writing it and then took a break to watch videos and then wrote it. We can not be sure that they have actually read the original answer or not. In this case normally a moderator uses her own common sense to judge the accusation. The case will be strong if the user has done it before.

Just remember that explaining a previous answer in another point of view is not a crime. They took some time to do it and deserve a credit (Reputation) for that. I have flagged more than one such answer which were declined giving this simple reason. In my personal opinion they need to be looked up thoroughly since I do not consider plagiarism as a good way of getting reputation. But in the end it all depends upon what the moderators think. And trust me, in most cases they are more right than you and me.

There's already a discussion on this [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300126/plagarism-when-is-a-similar-conclusion-acceptable) and some more at [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291276/are-duplicate-answers-acceptable/). Here's what Deduplicator said

> That is an easy and clear question, with a simple and straightforward
>   answer,
>
> Thus there's no wonder it attracted lots of fast, correct and nearly
>   identical answers. If you take a look, those three answers were posted
>   within a span of less than 4 minutes, the first one less than four
>   minutes after the queston.
>
> The answerers most likely didn't see each others answers until after
>   they posted. Naturally, you should take into account whether your
>   answer adds anything over pre-existing ones.
>
> As an aside, looks like the same happened here!

It looks like same happened here.

Comment: *Either downvote it or flag it as Custom flag to bring it in attention to a moderator* - None of the above mentioned options is correct. Down-vote an answer only if it is wrong, it is perfectly valid to have *similar* answers (which usually happens to lots of simple / common questions). There might have been a case where the OP might not have seen other answers. A duplicate answer is NOT the same as an incorrect answer. Also, never flag an answer for mods unless it is an emergency which SO community (other than the mods) can't handle.

Comment: I am saying the same thing. I just said that downvoting or flaging is the only option available.   
I don't agree with the emergency part. Brad Larson once mentioned that the mods use a script to identify the 'Other' flags which are mentioning Plagiarism in their description. That means they get it a lot and are OK with it.     
Source - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310836/should-i-do-anything-about-a-plagiarism-flag-i-raised-17-days-ago-thats-still-p

Comment: as to "same happened here" - nope. the (already deleted) answer appeared like more than 3 hours later. But thank you for your answer anyway, useful links!

Answer (score 4):

Depends on how different the answers are. If it is a [blatant copy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268629/1048572) of another answer, downvote and flag for moderator attention. Notice that similar-looking code is not necessary a sign of plagiarism, it just may be coincidence (standard answer to standard problem). Judge based on the rest of the answer, the timeline of the posts, and the experience of the authors.

Otherwise, if you feel that all is said already in existing answers, and the new post isn't even of above-average quality (or completeness), I tend to

- downvote
- possibly even vote for deletion, in the interest of clean-keeping a highly frequented question
- comment with something like "*This answer doesn't add anything over the existing ones*".

Comment: ok, this is what my question was, like "am I allowed to flag and vote for deleting an answer, which (as in example) brings 0% new info and repeats the existing one". Now I know, I am allowed to do so :)