# At what point is plagiarism an actionable offense?

Tags: discussion, plagiarism

I came upon a user yesterday that posted an answer that was plagiarized verbatim from another SO user without attribution. I then looked at several other answers from that user and discovered that they had repeatedly plagiarized from other SO answers and from other web sources. I flagged the ones I found and then moved on to other business as I didn't have the time to check all of their answers.

Are users disciplined at some point for this sort of behavior, and if so, what's the criteria?

Comment: I've seen users get suspended for a week when I've detected and flagged this.

Comment: There are suspensions; also getting a majority of their contributions nuked is punishment in itself. I'd be interested in knowing the user ID, I might be able to continue a bit where you left off

Comment: Users get [Larsoned](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/310842/578411)

Comment: @Pekka 웃: No need, already handled.

Comment: @BoltClock http://www.aviationspectator.com/files/images/McDonnell-Douglas-F-4-Phantom-II-238.preview.jpg